# DownloadPipelineArtifact@2 get build artificat from select branch

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines-yaml

I have a installer pipeline that you can manually run after regular build pipeline (which produces the application).

However, I need the installer to fetch the same build that I select when I run "installer pipeline".

```
- task: DownloadPipelineArtifact@2
  inputs:
    source: specific
    project: '$(System.TeamProjectId)'
    pipeline: 23
    path: '$(System.ArtifactsDirectory)'
    artifact: 'drop'
    runVersion: 'latestFromBranch'
```

and in the debug of the pipeline I get:
##[debug]PipelineId from non-trigerringBuild: (and wrong id here)

I run the installing pipeline manually selecting a branch/commit so it cant be hard-coded.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your error message

> ##[debug]PipelineId from non-trigerringBuild: (and wrong id here)

It indicates you have specified a invalid pipelineID, you could double-check this.

I have followed your steps to create an installer pipeline A to download the Pipeline Artifact from build pipeline B using [DownloadPipelineArtifact@2 task](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/reference/download-pipeline-artifact-v2?view=azure-pipelines)

Latest Artifact from main is 1590 and dev is 1593.

[image]

[image]

Running the installer pipeline manually by selecting main and dev.

Main:

[image]

Dev:

[image]

Here is the task sample:

```
- task: DownloadPipelineArtifact@2
  inputs:
    buildType: 'specific'
    project: '{Proj Name}}'
    definition: {definitionID}
    buildVersionToDownload: 'latestFromBranch'
    branchName: 'refs/heads/{branch name}'
```

Comment: Thank you for your work. "branchName: ref/heads/{branch name}" . Since I am manually triggering the build from a PR branch, I can't  have anything in the branchName value right?

"It indicates you have specified a invalid pipelineID, you could double-check this."
It does not complain that the pipelineId is wrong, just stating it is using 13865 (which is incorrect)
##[debug]PipelineId from non-trigerringBuild: 13865
^
right?

Comment: Better if you could share your whole workflow to me, if you are using a PR branch to trigger the build, we may need to modify the script, appreciated if you could specify your scenario.

Comment: actually adding the branchName and set it to $(Build.SourceBranch) seemed to work. So the key here was the  branchName parameter and buildVersionToDownload latestFromBranch.
Thank you